# Google Translate data tracked with gaTrack is not showing up in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-translate

I have a google translate widget on my website with `gaTrack` set to true and the correct `gaId`, but no translate events show up in analytics under content > Events > Overview after a week of the widget being live. The code snippet below was auto generated by the translate website, and works fine on the site. Any ideas why I'm not getting any translate events data?

```
<li>
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
            function googleTranslateElementInit() {
              new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-blahblah'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
            </script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure visitors have been using the widget?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The Translate events are not being captured in my analytics function googleTranslateElementInit() { new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,es,de,it,fr,nl,zh,de,he,ko,fi,ja,da,ru', gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-00000000-1', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }, 'google_translate_element'); }` <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>` I really have no idea, but I speculate this may have something to do with the difference between GA & Universal??

Comment: I think I am facing a similar issue. Since we have upgraded to UA, the Translate events have reduced significantly. Anyone have any luck with this ?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, and this solved it for me:

add the following code in the `<head> </head>` section of your website, for any pages using the Google Translate Plugin:

**If your website is HTTPS, add this snippet:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
```

**If your website is HTTP, add this snippet:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
```